# Cannot resolve symbol 'JwtConfigurer' IntellijDEA (windows10)

Tags: java, intellij-idea

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно видеть, они лежат в одном модуле (слева). Почему идея их не видит?

До этого все работало нормально - единственное изменение, на котором все сломалось - переключилась на другую ветку. Что самое невероятное, приложение нормально запускается на сервере томкат и исправно работает

Comment: скорее всего в файле jwtconfigurer неправильно указан package

Comment: пакет указан верно

Comment: тогда сделайте restart and invalidate cache в меню File

Comment: да) уже. Тыкни в ответах чтобы я отметила

Comment: да не, не страшно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот что решило мою проблему:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Похоже, идея иногда устает